# How can I solve this python problem?(Flask)

Tags: python, flask, mysql-connector-python

What's wrong with the code?
Solve please?
'''
#Code starts here

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
        import mysql.connector 
        from datetime import datetime
        import json
        
        
        
        app = Flask(__name__)
        
        @app.route("/")
        def home():
            return render_template('index.html', params=params)
        
        
        @app.route("/about")
        def about():
            return render_template('about.html', params=params)
        
       #problem appears here 
        @app.route("/contact", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
        f= open("config.json", 'r' ) 
        json.load(f)['params']
        mydb = params ['local_uri']
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        
        
        
        if(request.method=='POST'):
                    result = request.form.to_dict()
                    name = result['name']
                    phone_num= int(result['phone'])
                    email = result['email']
                    msg = result['message']
                    mycursor.execute("insert into Contacts(name,phone_num,email,msg) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)", (name,phone_num,email,msg))
                    mydb.commit()
                    mycursor.close()
                    return "success"
                return render_template('contact.html')   
        @app.route("/post")
        def post():
            return render_template('post.html',params=params)
        
        
        app.run(debug=True)'''
```

'''json.decoder.JSONDecodeError
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 5 column 44 (char 92)'''

Comment: what is your question? what is happening and how does that compare to what you expect to happen? Include any errors and tracebacks that you get

Comment: you have mentioned that "problem appears here", in that route there is no params declaration and you are trying to access it.

Comment: what error you are getting. correct your question with output and error so that community can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess what you're saying from this, but you haven't included the "def contact():" line which means that you've missed a bit of syntax. Try replacing that section of code with the below:

```
@app.route("/contact", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():
    f= open("config.json", 'r' ) 
    json.load(f)['params']
    mydb = params ['local_uri']
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
```